# What is the best way to install db on client machines?

Tags: java, database, web-applications, installation

We are starting to develop a web application which will be deployed on number of client sites. Web application will use a database like mysql or postgresql.

what are the ways in which we can make sure that the client is not able to access the db directly at all. We just want the client to use the web application which we will give to clients as .exe files.

basically we will be giving clients .exe which user can run and it will start web application and db etc. should not be visible to user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your architecture/question correctly, for PostgresSQL installs on Linux, you can configure the "local" parameter in pg_hba.conf to allow connections for specific users (peer authentication).
Hope this helps.